# How to get mongoDB collection size in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB DB, and make some processes on a collection, and close the collection when all the collection items were processed. when I'm trying to receive array.length, I get undefined.

```
Db = require('mongodb').Db;
Server = require('mongodb').Server;
const db = new Db(DB_NAME, new Server(HOST, PORT));
// connect to mongoDB
db.open(function (err, db) {
  const Collection = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
  var items = Collection.find({});
  var itemsLength = items.lebgth;
  var itemsProcessed = 0;
  items.forEach((item, index, array) => {
    // some process like:
    Collection.update({query}, {set}, callback)
    itemsProcessed++;
    if(itemsProcessed == array.length){
      db.close();
      // close connection if all items were processed
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Typo in `items.lebgth`.

Comment: items is cursor so you need to execute like: `var items = Collection.find({}).toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can use the optional callback of `forEach`, as documented [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#forEach):

```
items.forEach((item) => {
    // some process...
}, (err) => db.close()); // close connection if all items were processed
```

Comment: in this case items.hasNext() is a promise object. how can I do somthing like this: items.hasNext((has) => { if(!has) db.close(); } );

Comment: it works just partly, the callback raised up before processing all elements.

Comment: Sounds weird. Are you doing anything asynchronous inside the loop?

Comment: Well, that was an important bit of information to mention in the original question... I suggest that in the `forEach` loop you'd build the update query (that way it can be a single `update` with `multi=true` instead of many update calls), call `update` in the `forEach` callback, and call `db.close` in the `update` callback.

In addition, I suggest you'd edit your question and its title to better reflect what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `db.collection.count()`

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#stats)!

```
Collection.stat()
```